# Dimension mismatch between output mask and original mask in dice loss in Semantic segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am doing multi-class semantic segmentation(4 classes + background). My mask dimension is (256, 256, 3) and the output mask dimension is (256, 256, 5). I took 5 because it is the number of classes.

Dice Loss Function

```
inputs = inputs.view(-1)
targets = targets.view(-1)
        
intersection = (inputs * targets).sum() ---> error                       
dice = (2.*intersection + smooth)/(inputs.sum() + targets.sum() + smooth)  
        
return 1 - dice
```

What should I do to make the two dimensions the same? The mask was extracted from a TIF file.

I have attached my mask image below.
[image: My mask image]

Comment: Can you show the error message? What's the shape of `inputs`, and `targets`. Also, *"My mask dimension is (256, 256, 3) and the output mask dimension is (256, 256, 5)"* what do these two tensors refer to with respect to `inputs` and `targets`?

Comment: @Ivan I am doing semantic segmentation. Input Image Size is (256, 256, 3) and Model output is (256, 256, 5) because of 5 labels in the image. Target is the mask of the image which has a size of (256, 256, 3) i.e. the image in the question.

Comment: I have provided an answer, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the target segmentation you are showing is a RGB encoded map. You are looking to convert this 3-channel image into a 1-channel label map.

Assuming `seg` is your ground-truth segmentation map shaped as `(b, 3, h, w)`. The label to color mapping can be arbitrarily set as:

```
colors = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 0, 0],
                            [1, 1, 0],
                            [1, 0, 0],
                            [0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1]])
```

For each color construct a mask of matching pixel and assign the corresponding label in a new tensor at those pixel positions:

```
b, _, h, w = seg.shape
gt = torch.zeros(b,1,h,w)
seg_perm = seg.permute(0,2,3,1)

for label, color in enumerate(colors):
    mask = torch.all(seg_perm == color, dim=-1).unsqueeze(1)
    gt[mask] = label
```

---

For example taking the following segmentation map:

```
>>> seg = tensor([[[[1., 1., 0., 0.],
                    [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

                   [[0., 1., 0., 0.],
                    [0., 1., 0., 1.]],

                   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    [0., 0., 1., 0.]]]])
```

For visualization purposes:

```
>>> T.ToPILImage()(seg[0].repeat_interleave(100,2).repeat_interleave(100,1))
```

[image]

And the resulting label map will:

```
>>> gt
tensor([[[[2., 1., 0., 0.],
          [2., 3., 4., 3.]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must first one-hot encode the target mask.
I suggest you read this good article first to get a better grasp of all the subtleties of semantic segmentation https://www.jeremyjordan.me/semantic-segmentation/.

Make sure prediction and target shape match, no need to flatten tensors with `view(-1)`.

Also as a personal advice, prefer channel first for Pytorch tensors.

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem with how to match those 2 shapes because the target mask has 3 dimensions while the predicted mask has 5 due to 5 labels.
Yess channels are 1st

Comment: If I understand correctly you have to one-hot encode the target mask first.
If you have a target image with current pixel value equal to class (e.g. in range 0-4) you must convert it into a target image of shape 5xWxH with each pixel value being either 0-1 (one-hot encode it by class).
That 3 you have in the channel dimension of the target mask now I bet it's just a caveat of saving to .png.